# Unable to compile Android app - Error 256 in Corona

Tags: android, coronasdk, android-build

I am using Corona SDK and I am trying to compile my app for Android.  I have been able to compile for iOS.

When compiling using either a fully signed distribution key or a debug key I am given the following error:

`Build Failed: Error code: 256`

The full error is as follows:

```
Sep 23 01:24:00.635 Building Android app for mgr****@**.com with 2017.3135
Sep 23 01:24:02.541 BUILD SUCCESSFUL
                    Total time: 0 seconds
Sep 23 01:24:02.542 
Sep 23 01:25:24.905 BuildID: 59c5a9a30bb42
Sep 23 01:25:34.119      [exec] Result: 1
Sep 23 01:25:36.428 BUILD FAILED
                    /Applications/Corona/Corona Simulator.app/Contents/Resources/build.xml:479: The following error occurred while executing this line:
                    /Applications/Corona/Corona Simulator.app/Contents/Resources/build.xml:454: jarsigner returned: 1

                    Total time: 6 seconds
Sep 23 01:25:36.539 Android build failed (256) after 95 seconds
Sep 23 01:25:36.816 ERROR: Build Failed: Error code: 256
```

I have tried Google Play and Amazon targets with the same outcome.

Any ideas massively appreciated.

Comment: Try one of following: 1. Build project without icons in game folder 2. Uninstall and switch to  Java 6 3.Add right notification icon files in the project root. Read more on Corona forum about [Android build failed / Error code: 256](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/59905-android-build-failed-error-code-256/).

Comment: If the culprit in the build console is the notification icons, put the versionless (becomes v4 when building) icons listed at the top of this guide in the app folder. (i.e. Idurniat's #3) https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/events/appNotification/index.html#android-icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to compile the exact same files on a different machine (Windows) without an issue.  I guess this is down to the Java installation on the other machine.

Interestingly, Corona required the 32-bit version of Java on Windows, which meant downloading a slightly older SDK/JDK (latest SDK only has 64-bit builds).  My Mac has the latest 64-bit build, which Corona does not complain about, but isn't able to build with.

Comment: I am able to build using the latest Java SE (JDK 9.0.1) here, if that helps. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html